# Rounding arithmetic in accounting

Tags: math, rounding

### Note

This is for an accounting software, so the values are rounded to cents (2 decimal places).

### Question

Given the final value invoice value of $4488.70 (we can call this value `final`), obtain the initial subtotal value (`subtotal`) in such a way that:

`subtotal` + `round(0.07 * subtotal)` - `round(0.02 * subtotal)` = `final`

For the case of `final` being $4488.70,
by directly doing division by 1.02 and obtaining $4400.6862745 (rounded to $4400.69)

For an invoice, this wouldn't tally because:

```
Subtotal    4400.69
VAT (7%)     308.05  ==> round(4400.69 * 0.07)
WHT (5%)     220.03  ==> round(4400.69 * 0.05)
==========
Final       4488.71 (4400.69 + 308.05 - 220.03)
```

That is not the wanted final value (off by 1 cent).

The better subtotal here should instead be 4400.68, but how do we obtain that algorithmically?

```
Subtotal    4400.68
VAT (7%)     308.05  ==> round(4400.68 * 0.07)
WHT (5%)     220.03  ==> round(4400.68 * 0.05)
==========
Final       4488.70 (4400.68 + 308.05 - 220.03)
```

### Current proposed solution

Internally we are proposing doing a 3 passes by firstly obtain tentative `subtotal = final/1.02`, and work forward to see if we get the final intended value, if not, we try `subtotal - 1` and ultimately `subtotal + 1`.

- Pass 1: `final/1.02`
- Pass 2: `final/1.02 - 0.01`
- Pass 3: `final/1.02 + 0.01`

Is there a better, more efficient and still as reliable method as the proposed one?

Comment: I smell GST in this question. sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not achievable *in general*. There might be some value `final` for which no such `subtotal` exists. (I'm too lazy to do a mathematical proof now, but I'm sure that some value can be found for which `subtotal` yields `desiredFinal - 0.01` and `subtotal + 0.01` yields `desiredFinal + 0.01` due to the way rounding is performed).

There are two common ways to solve this:

1. `subtotal = final/1.02`, then calculate everything else, like you did in your first example:

   ```
   Subtotal    4400.69
   VAT (7%)     308.05  ==> round(4400.69 * 0.07)
   WHT (5%)     220.03  ==> round(4400.69 * 0.05)
   ==========
   Final       4488.71 (4400.69 + 308.05 - 220.03)
   ```

   If there is a cent difference, add or remove it from `subtotal` and `final`. That means that VAT and WHT won't be precise w.r.t. `subtotal`.

   ```
   Subtotal    4400.68  ==> one cent removed
   VAT (7%)     308.05
   WHT (5%)     220.03
   ==========
   Final       4488.70  ==> one cent removed
   ```
2. Explicitly mention the rounding error:

   ```
   Subtotal    4400.69
   VAT (7%)     308.05
   WHT (5%)     220.03
   Rounding    -  0.01
   ==========
   Final       4488.70
   ```

Which one to choose depends on your local tax legislation.

Comment: Thanks, so it's still 3 passes. Now I wonder if the 3rd pass could be eliminated and only needing 2 passes (probably not). Rounding wouldn't be correct as the final value may not always ends in nice number, it could be .78, making the rounding looks weird to the recipient of the the said invoice.

Comment: @uzyn: Actually, it's only one pass: Calcuate subtotal, calculate (new) final, add difference between final and expected final to subtotal. Keep VAT and WHT as they are.